# Scilab installed but application does not start

Tags: applications

I have installed [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org) a few weeks ago, and when I tried it for the first time it worked, but now when I try to run it, it seems it will open (it jumps) the application, but nothing happens actually.

What could be the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is because when I first installed `Scilab` I hadn't already updated my Mac to the `Yosemite` version. Therefore I had installed `Scilab` not for the `Yosemite` version, but for the previous one.

What made me think this was that in the official website of `Scilab` it's written that for `Yosemite` versions, we should install this [Scilab 5.5.1 - Mac OS X 10.10
148.82 MB](http://www.scilab.org/download/5.5.1) version, and probably I had not installed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are right about it being OS compatibility then yes installing the latest version which works fine for me on Yosemite should work.

To answer your question about the upgrade: If I remember correctly scilab is a standard Mac install via a .dmg and drag the application to the Applications folder.

If this is the case then just download the latest .dmg from here - http://www.scilab.org/download/5.5.1 (make sure to download the one verified for 10.10), mount it and copy the application to the Applications folder overwriting the previous version. And now it should work. Let  me know if it doesn't.